# trouble adding background image to my jpanel, can't find error, I didn't understood the error also

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test 
    {

    public static void panel1()
    {
            JFrame frame=new JFrame("@b's metric calculator");
            //Color b=new Color(0,150,255);
            //JPanel Cr=new JPanel();
            final JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
            //textField.setBackgound(0,255,220);
            JButton button=new JButton("Enter Centimeter");
            final JTextField textFiel= new JTextField("Your result will be here",20);
            String[] list = {"cm-inch","cm-meter","cm-feet","inch-feet"};
            /*The <string> added below is to avoid "unchecked or unsafe operations” warning in Java ,
            if passing integer set it <Integer>*/
            final JComboBox<String> list1 = new JComboBox<String>(list);
            list1.setSelectedIndex(0);
            JButton submit=new JButton("Submit");
            submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {   
                //textFiel.setText(textField.getText());

                //following command converts textfild value to integer
                int centi=Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                //----------------------------------------------------
                //double area = 3.14*radius*radius;
                int cb = list1.getSelectedIndex();//to get the index of selected item(eg. 0,1,2..)
                if(cb==0)
                {   
                    Double inch = centi/2.54;
                    //following command converts double to string
                    String out = Double.toString(inch);
                    //-----------------------------------------
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                }
                else if(cb==1)
                {   
                    Double meter = centi/100.00;
                    String out = Double.toString(meter);
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                }
                else if(cb==2)
                {   
                    Double feet = centi/30.48;
                    String out = Double.toString(feet);
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                }
                else 
                {   
                    Double feet = centi/12.00;
                    String out = Double.toString(feet);
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                }
                }
            });
            //c.setBackground(b);
            frame.add(new Cr());
            Cr.add(button);
            Cr.add(textField);
            Cr.add(list1);
            Cr.add(submit);
            Cr.add(textFiel);
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(400,300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Welcome \n enter centimeter in blank box\n Select your choice\n then press submit");
    }   
        class Cr extends JPanel{

            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");
            public void paint( Graphics g ) {
            Dimension d = getSize();
            for( int x = 0; x < d.width; x += image.getIconWidth() )
            for( int y = 0; y < d.height; y += image.getIconHeight() )
            g.drawImage( image.getImage(), x, y, null, null );
            super.paint(g);
            }           
            } 


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
             {
                        public void run() {
                                 panel1();
                                  }
            });
        }


}
```

problem code is this section,it started when i tried to add image to panel.

```
class Cr extends JPanel{

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");
        public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        Dimension d = getSize();
        for( int x = 0; x < d.width; x += image.getIconWidth() )
        for( int y = 0; y < d.height; y += image.getIconHeight() )
        g.drawImage( image.getImage(), x, y, null, null );
        super.paint(g);
        }           
        }
```

can you pls help me guys ,pls say which all i have to change.
it says error non-static variable can't be referenced from a static context. thks in advance.
**thks to every one and 'vedant1811' for the layout idea ,'mKorbel' for overriding paint and 'nIcE cOw' for putting my code on center ,i used it now i made my program finally working. thks**

> **My final code**

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test extends JPanel{

    public Test() {

    setOpaque(false);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("@b's metric calculator"); 
        final JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        JButton button = new JButton("Enter Centimeter");
        final JTextField textFiel = new JTextField("Your result will be here", 20);
        String[] list = {"cm-inch", "cm-meter", "cm-feet", "inch-feet"};
        /*The <string> added below is to avoid "unchecked or unsafe operations” warning in Java ,
        if passing integer set it <Integer>*/
        final JComboBox<String> list1 = new JComboBox<String>(list);
        list1.setSelectedIndex(0);
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        Test Cr = new Test();
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //textFiel.setText(textField.getText());

                //following command converts textfild value to integer
                int centi = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                //----------------------------------------------------
                //double area = 3.14*radius*radius;
                int cb = list1.getSelectedIndex();//to get the index of selected item(eg. 0,1,2..)
                if (cb == 0) {
                    Double inch = centi / 2.54;
                    //following command converts double to string
                    String out = Double.toString(inch);
                    //-----------------------------------------
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                } else if (cb == 1) {
                    Double meter = centi / 100.00;
                    String out = Double.toString(meter);
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                } else if (cb == 2) {
                    Double feet = centi / 30.48;
                    String out = Double.toString(feet);
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                } else {
                    Double feet = centi / 12.00;
                    String out = Double.toString(feet);
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                }
            }
        }); 
        frame.add(Cr);      
        Cr.add(button);
        Cr.add(textField);
        Cr.add(list1);
        Cr.add(submit);
        Cr.add(textFiel);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 30));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Welcome \n enter centimeter in blank box\n Select your choice\n then press submit");
    }   
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        // Loads the background image and stores in img object.
        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\JAVA\\My java programs\\hd_wall_11493.jpg");
        // Draws the img to the BackgroundPanel.
        g.drawImage(img,0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height,this);
        super.paint(g);
    }
    }
```

Comment: When you are extending a `JPanel` never override it's `paint(...) method, inside always choose `paintComponent(...)`, that's is the way to go, as far as the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html) are concerned

Comment: Please do have a look at this example, for [How to put images in your Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception/9866659#9866659). Moreover, in order to bring the frame to the center of the screen, simply write `frameObject.setLocationRelativeTo(null)`, before `frameObject.setVisible(true);`, that's it :-)

Comment: thks for the code for center screen.

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 2):

don't want to comment something

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("@b's metric calculator");
        //Color b=new Color(0,150,255);
        //JPanel Cr=new JPanel();
        final JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        //textField.setBackgound(0,255,220);
        JButton button = new JButton("Enter Centimeter");
        final JTextField textFiel = new JTextField("Your result will be here", 20);
        String[] list = {"cm-inch", "cm-meter", "cm-feet", "inch-feet"};
        /*The <string> added below is to avoid "unchecked or unsafe operations” warning in Java ,
        if passing integer set it <Integer>*/
        final JComboBox<String> list1 = new JComboBox<String>(list);
        list1.setSelectedIndex(0);
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //textFiel.setText(textField.getText());

                //following command converts textfild value to integer
                int centi = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                //----------------------------------------------------
                //double area = 3.14*radius*radius;
                int cb = list1.getSelectedIndex();//to get the index of selected item(eg. 0,1,2..)
                if (cb == 0) {
                    Double inch = centi / 2.54;
                    //following command converts double to string
                    String out = Double.toString(inch);
                    //-----------------------------------------
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                } else if (cb == 1) {
                    Double meter = centi / 100.00;
                    String out = Double.toString(meter);
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                } else if (cb == 2) {
                    Double feet = centi / 30.48;
                    String out = Double.toString(feet);
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                } else {
                    Double feet = centi / 12.00;
                    String out = Double.toString(feet);
                    textFiel.setText(out);
                }
            }
        });
        //c.setBackground(b);
        Cr cr = new Cr();
        cr.add(button);
        cr.add(textField);
        cr.add(list1);
        cr.add(submit);
        cr.add(textFiel);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 30));
        frame.add(cr);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Welcome \n enter centimeter in blank box\n Select your choice\n then press submit");
    }

    class Cr extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Dimension d = getSize();
            for (int x = 0; x < d.width; x += image.getIconWidth()) {
                for (int y = 0; y < d.height; y += image.getIconHeight()) {
                    g.drawImage(image.getImage(), x, y, null, null);
                }
            }
            super.paint(g);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Test test = new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling this might still pop up an error. Did you compile it? I may be wrong. :-)

Comment: Yes. I did mean that. Will have to do a bit of reading on it I suppose. :-)

Comment: thks for the reply the program works error free ,but i didn't understood "private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;" ,what does this mean ,also the image is not showing only blank background ,could you pls help me once more. thks

Comment: @TomC: see Bloch, _Effective Java_, Item 74: Implement Serializable judiciously.

Answer (score 2):

I'll explain you your error:
Your test() method is a static method. It cannot access non-static methods/variables directly (this makes perfect programming sense, comment if you want me to elaborate). Static methods and variables can only access static members. You need to create an object of a static member and that object can access other non-static members.

As for the corrections required in your code, mKorbel's solution is perfect. However, to add an image to a JPanel, its best to "add" it as a JLabel, rather than to draw it. :

```
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("path-to-file"));
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
frame.add( picLabel );//see javadocs for JLabel for more info
```

**EDIT**

But you need a background image. The following is the corrected code:

```
class Cr extends JPanel{
    //change here ('\\' is the escape sequence for '\') :
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg");
    public void paint( Graphics g ) {
    Dimension d = getSize();
    for( int x = 0; x < d.width; x += image.getIconWidth() )
    for( int y = 0; y < d.height; y += image.getIconHeight() )
    g.drawImage( image.getImage(), x, y, null, null );
    super.paint(g);
    }           
}
```

Comment: thks ,i am new to java ,so little knowledge in static stuffs . also mKorbel's solution is excellent ,but i didn't understood "private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;" ,what does this mean ,also the image is not showing only blank background ,could you pls help me,image is located in 'C' drive -my pictures.

Comment: "private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;" is a variable that stores the serial Version of your program. It is redundant in your case (that was added by the IDE). you can delete it if you want.

Comment: it must be stupid for me to ask ,but i am a starter so please excuse me for asking ,should i use it in class cr instead of ImageIcon?

Comment: use it in your panel1() method (where you have created the fame = new JFrame and added other components). that's where you have used your "frame" object, and only there will frame.add(picLabel); work

Comment: finally i found why my image was not loading ,it should be in my class folder ,thks for your hlp guys . thks to both vedant1811 and mKorbel for your assistance.

Comment: ya i just realized you don't want to add an image, u want to use it as a background. Then the code you have is fine, except you will need to edit: ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg");  i hope this is self-explanatory. You can use any path using this technique but it's better to use the default path for portability

Comment: i tried using buffered image and got this as output [link]http://i47.tinypic.com/c57jk.png -my new code i have shown above in my first post. Why is the background at top portion, not showing the image?also how can i show my frame at center of my monitor's screen, currently it is loaded at top-left corner. thks pls reply

Comment: Yes that's because this the JLabel is taking the entire area of the frame. This isn't a discussion forum, since your question is answered you should get back to work and post new questions if you encounter further problems. For learning java Swing, see the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: Use the LayoutManager for your JFrame.